# Bash: wait for image to be available in dockerhub

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a bash script that will download the image from docker hub if present else it will wait for 5 mins before exiting

```
#!/bin/sh

waitForDockerImage=0
res='Error response from daemon'
while [[ "${res}" == *"Error response from daemon"* ]]; do
    echo $res
    res=$(docker pull node/base-alpine:test)
    echo $res
    waitForDockerImage=$(($waitForDockerImage+10))
    if [ $waitForDockerImage -gt 300 ];then
        echo "waited for 5 mins, exiting now.."
        exit
    else
        sleep 1 # wait for 1 the second before check again
    fi
done
```

Also, while loop is running for the 1st iteration time but failing on the 2nd iteration.
For the 2nd run

```
res=Error response from daemon: manifest for Error response from daemon: manifest for not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

So I am checking if res contains `Error response from daemon`

Comment: Don't use `/bin/sh` and `[[` in one script. `[[` is a bashism, while `/bin/sh` might be something else than bash.

Answer (score 1):

The error response is written to standard error, not standard output. It works the first time because you manually set `res`, rather than failing to capture standard error from `docker`. Change the assignment in the loop to

```
res=$(docker pull node/base-alpine:test 2>&1)
```

Better yet, ignore the standard error and test the exit status of `docker pull`.

```
i=0
while :;do
    docker pull node/base-alpine:test 2>/dev/null && break
    if [ "$i" -gt 300 ]; then
        printf 'Waited 5 minutes, exiting now\n' >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
    sleep 1
done
```

Since you are using `bash`, though, it's easy to check if 5 minutes have passed without using a counter as a proxy.

```
SECONDS=0
while :; do
    docker pull node/base-alpine:test 2>/dev/null && break
    if (( $SECONDS > 300 )); then
        printf 'Waited 5 minutes, exiting now\n' >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

`SECONDS` is a special variable in `bash` whose value is effectively incremented once per second.

Comment: If the OP changes to bash from `sh`, it would make sense to use `$SECONDS` instead of `$i` -- as written right now it's liable to wait more than 5 minutes, because the `docker pull` attempts aren't instant.

Comment: I was thinking about that. The expected failure, though, seems to be that the requested image doesn't exist, which will happen more or less instantaneously. Unless the concern is that a long transfer will start and repeatedly fail in the middle, I don't think it's worth trying to make a strict distinction between "try for 5 minutes' and "try 300 times". (Though with `$SECONDS`, that distinction does become trivial to make.)